# Ubuntu 22.04 Usrmerge fatal error

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

While upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 this fatal error occurred.

```
FATAL ERROR:
Both /bin/systemd-tmpfiles and /usr/bin/systemd-tmpfiles exist.

You can try correcting the errors reported and running again
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge until it will complete without errors.
Do not install or update other Debian packages until the program
has been run successfully.

dpkg:  error when processing package usrmerge (--configure):   
subprocess of package usrmerge was installed script post-installation  
returned error value 1 Errors found while processing: usrmerge  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: From which version of Ubuntu you try to upgrade to 22.04?

Comment: From 20.04 to 22.04

Comment: Have you tried to run `sudo /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge`?

Comment: Yes, I did.
sudo /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge
Smartmatch is experimental at /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge line 172.

FATAL ERROR:
Both /bin/systemd-tmpfiles and /usr/bin/systemd-tmpfiles exist.

You can try correcting the errors reported and running again
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge until it will complete without errors.
Do not install or update other Debian packages until the program
has been run successfully.

Comment: /usr/bin$  rm systemd-tmpfiles

rm: normaal bestand 'systemd-tmpfiles' (schrijfbeveiligd) verwijderen? y
rm: kan 'systemd-tmpfiles' niet verwijderen: Toegang geweigerd

Comment: After all, I was able to delete the file and more. There were about 10 files that were duplicates. Now it works again. Thx Lorenz.

Comment: Use dpkg to verify which of the two files is managed by the package manager, and remove the other one: `dpkg -S {/usr,}/bin/systemd-tmpfiles`. This will give you enough info to solve the issues of existing files. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

A whole series of bugs on the usrmerge implementation has been
opened:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usrmerge/+bugs?field.status:list=NEW

The reason for usrmerge to exist in the first place is rooted in the unix history far back to the 1970s. See e.g. https://lwn.net/Articles/477467/

the README of the usrmerge package tries to explain a bit (be prepared that this is all very cryptic ...)
https://salsa.debian.org/md/usrmerge/raw/master/debian/README.Debian

The bad news is that if you call

```bash
sudo /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge
```

you will have to manually work on the problems shown in stepwise fashion.

E.g. I got a duplicate evince in /bin/evince and /usr/bin/evince - compared the two and removed /bin/evince

then

```bash
FATAL ERROR:
Both /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 and /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 exist.

You can try correcting the errors reported and running again
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge until it will complete without errors.
Do not install or update other Debian packages until the program
has been run successfully.
```

beware not to remove /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 - it will make your system unusable and you'll have to fix things using e.g. a USB bootstick

I had to restore this symlink:

```bash
root@my_computer:/lib64# ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 Jul  7 01:23 ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

I ended up to get rid of the package and wait until the dust settles and the developers get their act together to better describe how to fix things in a language that mere mortal might understand:

```bash
sudo apt remove --purge usrmerge
```

Comment: Did the same for the upgrade 20.04 to 22.04.1

It is a shame that with the 'normal' update to a point-release (22.04.1), nobody cared to prevent the upgrade from failing out; despite this thing being known for half a year.

Comment: Many thanks for your hints.
I first underestimated the "beware not to remove /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2".
When you remove it, you CANNOT execute any command, even "ln", so you really have to use the USB stick.

However, I was a little bit more adventurous, and when I used the USB bootstick, I have created "final symlink" instead:
________
    ln -s /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
________
=> rebooted to normal system.
I then it finished correctly:
________
    /usr/lib/convert-usrmerge
    The system has been successfully converted.
________

Comment: I wonder whether this is the reason why usrmerge package authors cannot fix the current conversion script. Since at this point, they cannot use even "ln" command. Maybe they will have to rewrite the "perl script" (or what it is) to some compiled binary (e.g. writted in C, and using direct symlink call without a need for executing a new program, which seems to stop working when you remove ld-linux-x86-64.so.2).

Comment: @udippel how did you make the upgrade if usrmerge is failing ? I do not have usrmerge, it is brought by the upgrade, and then failing :(

Comment: @Ciprian: My memory fails me w.r.t. the details. Very sorry, too long ago.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not usrmerge itself, it is the problem that usrmerge is trying to solve. When one package installs a library in /lib and another the same one in /usr/lib, this is going to be an issue. usrmerge solves this by symlinking everything so there is no longer any confusion about where the libraries should be installed.

On top of that, in my case, there was a library that had the 'immutable' attribute, that meant that there was no way for usrmerge (or dpkg, for that matter!) to remove or replace the file. This lead to another consequential issue (2 below).

There are three categories of issues here:

1. The above: a file that can not be modified. You should check this with `lsattr` and remove the `a` and `i` flags with `chattr -i -a /the/file`
2. usrmerge creates temporary symlinks while reorganizing the file system. These files can easily be removed by a `find / -name "*~usrmerge* -delete`
3. Finally, when duplicates have arisen, the way to remove them is to check whether one of the two is managed by `dpkg` or not. One of them certainly isn't, so you should remove that one:

```
dpkg -S {/usr,}/lib/a
a:amd64: /usr/lib/a
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/a
```

In that case, `/lib/a` can be removed and the convert-usrmerge can be run again. With a little elbow grease you can turn this into a script that will parse the output convert-usrmerge and the above dpkg command and iteratively fix all your issues, which I did too.

DISCLAIMER: I unfortunately needed to rollback the system because of other issues and no longer have the exact commands nor the script, so I typed the above from the top of my head. Please be prudent as you should with stuff like this.