# Upgrade trouble 20.04 to 22.04.1 usrmerge

Tags: apt, upgrade

An otherwise unspectacular upgrade, towards the end it failed and ended me at the prompt. After reboot I have no WiFi on a WiFi-only device. Then, apt get update / upgrade warn me to rectify some usrmerge problem; the one that earlier, during the upgrade had thrown me out already:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  apport apport-kde guile-2.2-libs python3-apport python3-problem-report
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up usrmerge (25ubuntu2) ...
Smartmatch is experimental at /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge line 172.
cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/opt/lib/libmediaclient.so': No such file or directory

FATAL ERROR:
cp --no-dereference --preserve=all --reflink=auto --sparse=always /opt/lib/libmediaclient.so /usr/opt/lib/libmediaclient.so: rc=1

You can try correcting the errors reported and running again
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge until it will complete without errors.
Do not install or update other Debian packages until the program
has been run successfully.

dpkg: error processing package usrmerge (--configure):
 installed usrmerge package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 usrmerge
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What's wrong, what could I do?

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406991/ubuntu-22-04-usrmerge-fatal-error

Comment: Thanks a lot. Helps! Somehow it hadn't popped up when writing the question.